# Freezing & nonresponsive after starting Zoom video chat

Tags: release-hera, thirdpartyapps

I am using Zoom video chat and it works well except that every time I start a video call or join an existing one, Zoom and all other applications freeze and become unresponsive for a period of about 2 minutes. After this time, everything comes back and behaves well throughout the duration of the Zoom call.

I am on 5.1.3 Hera

I installed the .deb ([here](https://zoom.us/download?os=linux)) using

> sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb

Anyone run into this issue? Or more generally does anyone have experience getting Zoom to behave well on Elementary? Perhaps with a different installation method or configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've use zoom almost every day, and it's working pretty well. You should try to purge that zoom first and install it with Eddy.

You can download Eddy from the app center just search Eddy. These apps will install all your .deb files automatically.

Or maybe you can see the task processes on command

```
htop
```

and see how much zoom eats your resources. Freezing apps probably happen when your memory doesn't have enough resources to run the program.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I tried purging and reinstalling via eddy. When I start a Zoom call htop shows a massive spike in CPU usage from some xorg process called lightdm. Not sure what that's about but it gives me a clue.